# Classical pieces with Latin lyrics: sicut erat in principio et nunc

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

Can't identify what this is. Please help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The latin text is "Sicut erat in principio, et nunc et semper, et in saecula saeculorum. Amen" : English "as it was in the beginning, is now and ever shall be, world without end. Amen", the so-called ["Gloria Patri"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxology#Gloria_Patri)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Googling **BA 5340a**, I've found [Mozart's *DIXIT ET MAGNIFICAT KV 193 (BA 5340A)*](http://www.musik-mueller.de/index.php?Artikelnummer=BA+5340A&page=shop.product_details&flypage=shop.flypage&product_id=91896&category_id=12&manufacturer_id=0&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=104&vmcchk=1&Itemid=104).

This youtube [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5bPIjSHdu-A) confirms the piece is in **latin language**, **religious choir** in **C major** key.

The sheet starts [around 8:50](https://youtu.be/5bPIjSHdu-A?t=530), when you can hear the transition between 3 times / 4 times signature, and the lyrics match too.